# Как сделать проверку закрыта ли программа в коде на python

Tags: python-3.x, проверка

Всем здраствуйте.У меня появилась такая проблема что мне нужно сделать скрипт на python, который будет проверять открыта ли программа или нет. Нужно мне это для программы ChessBotX trial. И вопрос как это сделать мне. Если нельзя на pyton то подскажите как на c#. Заранее благодарю.

Answer (score 0):

Можно воспользоваться библиотекой `pymem`

```
import pymem

try:
    pymem.Pymem("cmd.exe")
    print("Приложение запущено...")
except:
    print("Приложение не запущено...")
```

Comment: Помогло. Все работает. Спасибо огромное!!!

Comment: Если ответ решают вашу проблему, поставьте галочку напротив него